# Lookup Azure application name from within a running function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Is it possible to lookup the application name for an Azure app as it runs, i.e., get the information about that is displayed in the Azure portal?  In the example below, I'd want something to tell me from within the application that I am running `sitemap-prod-eastus`.

I've been looking at the [Azure Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/context?view=azure-node-latest) object but not seeing what I need.  There is an invocation ID, a name for the function, a directory - not the info in this window.

Maybe this can be done through Azure Application Insights?

I am working in Node JS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: Azure provides `WEBSITE_SITE_NAME` in the runtime environment that matches the name of the function app.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen anything that would expose this to a function app. That said, there is one sort of workaround that you could do which would work - go to the Configuration blade for the function app, Application settings tab, and add a configuration key like `function_name` and set its value to the name of your app. Your app could then just read it out of configuration.

It's an extra step, but if you're doing it with something like ARM or Terraform, it's just another configuration entry with a variable you already declared to set up the app in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, I was moving to that but then discovered WEBSITE_SITE_NAME.  See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70993431/688448